# Multiple objects/parts are selected in object mode

Tags: modeling

As noted in the title, when I switch into Object mode, several separate objects are highlighted as one. Is there any way to make them separate?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have joined all of those parts into a single object, as can be seen in the outliner where it shows only one object is selected.  You need to go back into edit mode and separate the objects if you wish to have them become separate parts.

In edit mode, select one part, perhaps by *island select*; (shortcut <kbd>L</kbd>) box select; or other means and *separate* them. (shortcut <kbd>P</kbd> and select *Selection*.)